# Java: String vs. custom class for storing a point

Tags: java, memory, ram

I am dealing with a large set of X,Y,Z points. What will be the best way to store all of the points if I need to keep RAM usage low? A string "X,Y,Z", a custom class, or would it not make any difference either way?

Comment: What precision do you need for the coordinates?

Comment: What about javax.vecmath.Point3d? I haven't used this ever, but this is the first result on google search. -- Never mind, its not default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strings are almost definitely a wrong choice: they waste about half the space, if not more, and they make you waste CPU cycles to get the data back into the numeric format suitable for processing.

A custom class with three primitive fields is a much better choice. Depending on the range and the type of your points, use `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`. This helps you avoid parsing the coordinates every time you are about to use your points.

Comment: I know this has already been highly upvoted and accepted. This solution is not bad, but the solution suggested by Nikolay Kuznetsov is much better in this situation.

Comment: @SamuelRossille One should always strive for a good balance of readability vs. performance/memory compactness/cache requirements and so on. Storing all points in the same array in groups of three give you the smallest possible footprint at the expense of destroying the readability. To me, this is a very high price. If your performance requirements are such that you cannot avoid it, then you do what you have to do, and throw everything in a single array. If your requirements are more relaxed, however, a `Point` class with intuitive semantic provides for much better readability.

Comment: It doesn't destroy readability at all if you wrap the whole array with a class with methods like i suggested in my edit on Nikolay Kuznetsov's post. `geometry.getX(42)` would be as readable as something like `points[42].getX()`

Comment: @SamuelRossille Speaking of your edit, I think changed the meaning of Nikolay's answer quite a bit. In fact, it sounds almost like a new answer. As far as the efficiency goes, your solution calls for three accesses to an array vs. one, plus three additional calculations on the index. It would still save some memory and may be fast enough in the end, but then again this solution could have an acceptable memory footprint. At any rate, I wouldn't declare one solution **much** better than the other without some serious profiling, and even then I'd take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Just to explain my point: I worked on an application that had huge slowness issue. The application offered a service that required a lot of computing. We first implemented it in the most natural way, by implementing our model with java classes. While profiling we noticed that most of the CPU was used in garbage collection. This was due to a large number of small object created and destroyed all the time. Re-factoring some parts to use tables with exactly the same algorithms solved the issues.

Comment: I agree with you on the word "much". It would require in depth verification. But it was necessary to draw attention on these issues, and keep in mind that one way that could seem to use more CPU could in the end use much less because of a lower cost of garbage collection. Anyways you are right that the default approach should be writing classes and that we mush not early - optimize something that might just work.

Answer (score 2):

Why not an array with 3 elements?

Answer (score 2):

You can make one array to store X, Y, Z together, if you want to achieve low memory usage.

For a point with index i you can store X, Y, Z in array elements with following indexes:

- 0 + 3*i for X
- 1 + 3*i for Y
- 2 + 3*i for Z

**Edit:** This approach also has the following important advantages, which might in some circumstances be very handy:

- Puts all the data of the geometry algorithm in a contiguous place in memory, making CPU cache much more efficient.
- It's doesn't clutter memory management with a ton of small objects.

You can of course wrap this big table with a class with methods like `getX(int index)` to make it more readable for a little CPU cost.